# Scroll text vertically with word wrap

Tags: c#, forms, c#-4.0

I have some variable length text that, when necessary, I would like to scroll vertically. An example can be seen here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77be2b96-b4b4-462c-b6d0-66c2c9739420/scroll-text-vertically
The problem with the solution in this example is that it does not word wrap the text. I have also seen examples where text is painted inside of a rectangle and then the rectangle is moved to produce the effect of scrolling text but I don't think this will work for me. I have controls above and below where I want to scroll the text and the text height is taller than the height of the screen.

My current OnPaintEvent:

```
private void JvsMessageLabelPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.mLabelToScrollVertically.Text,
        this.mLabelToScrollVertically.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
        this.mLabelToScrollVertically.Location.X, yPositionForLabel);
    yPositionForLabel -= 5;
    if (yPositionForLabel < this.mLabelToScrollVertically.Location.Y)
    {
        yPositionForLabel = this.mLabelToScrollVertically.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the [`TextRenderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I have but I didn't see how I could scroll the text using that class.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the [DrawString overload with the target rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/19sb1bw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I could but then how do I scroll? My current code scrolls with no word wrap. Both suggestions can word wrap but are unable to scroll text larger than the max space I could allocate for text to be displayed (as far as I can tell).

Comment: You are right. I have posted a workaround, not sure if you like it or can even use it, but as you can see it is really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not sure if you can use it but here is a common workaround to create a Control with `ScrollBars`:

Place the `Panel` **inside** another `Panel` . Make the outer `Panel` `AutoScroll=true` and change the `Height` of the inner one to what you have measured the text to take..

Here is the `Paint` event and the result:

```
private void pan_text_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   string text = yourLongText;

   SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, Font, pan_text.ClientSize.Width);

   pan_text.Height = (int) size.Height;

   e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, size) );

}
```

- If instead of `ScrollBars` for the user you want a scrolling **animation**, the same trick will work.

Just **don't** make the outer `Panel AutoScroll` and add a `Timer`:

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 15;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Start();
}

void timer1_Tick2object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pan_image.Top -= 2;
    if (pan_image.Top < -pan_image.Height) pan_image.Top = 0;
}
```

- In fact for a simple animation you don't need the outer `Panel` at all!

Simply define a class variable to hold the current position you want to draw the text at and use this `Tick` event:

```
int curTop = 0;

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    curTop -= 2;
    if (curTop < -pan_image.Height) curTop = 0;
    pan_image.Invalidate();
}
```

Now if you use it in the `DrawString` the same effect will show:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, Brushes.Black, 
                      new RectangleF(new PointF(0, curTop), size) );
```

(Of course, since the `Panel` is no longer contained in the outer one you don't change its `Height`!)

[image]

Comment: This would indeed allow scrolling but through the use of the traditional scrollbar. Ultimately I'll probably use a textbox with scrollbars but I would still like to know how I can have auto scrolling text similar to what was in the link but also with word wrap.

Comment: I see. You could still try to do it without scrollbars (autoscroll=false) and move the inner panel up and down in your scrolling code..

Comment: Finally looked at the link. sorry to do it so late, I usually avoid social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums.. The both coded answers can easily be mended to work with word wrap as my code above does. In fact the second one moves the Panel just like I do and in the first one, where the drawing location is being incremented all you need to change it to give the bounding Rectangle as I do, too.

Comment: You are right, that would work. Could I also achieve this same effect if I drew one rectangle inside of another and moved the inner rectangle up and down?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. You can move Controls and you can change the location of a Rectangle (or rather create a Rectangle with a changed location). You can't move pixels. You can use a class variable `int curTop`, increment it in the `Tick` and use it in the `Paint` to create a location like this: `new Point( 0, curTop)` in the `DrawString`. `Invalidate` in the `Tick` and the effect should work as well..

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. You have definitely given me a few on how to achieve the effect I wanted.